# explain javascript regex by breaking into smaller pieces

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a function to extract the video id from youtube urls.

```
 function youtubeLinkParser(url) {
            var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
            var match = url.match(regExp);
            if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
                return match[2];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I'm new to regex, so would any one mind breaking up the regex into smaller pieces and explain how it works.

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/

Comment: plz specify reason for negative votes?

Comment: I downvoted because RegEx explaining is rather trivial with regexper.com and similar things. The purpose of SO is supposed to be for not just you, but future visitors as well, and frankly this question is too localized.

Comment: Automatically generated explanations are fine, but no tool can tell you that this expression is poorly written (`^.*`, `\&` etc), and maybe even incorrect (mixing domain and parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation from Yape::Regex::Explain

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^.*(youtu.be/|v/|u/\w/|embed/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    youtu                    'youtu'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    be/                      'be/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    v/                       'v/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    u/                       'u/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    embed/                   'embed/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    watch                    'watch'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \?                       '?'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    v=                       'v='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \&                       '&'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    v=                       'v='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^#\&\?]*                any character except: '#', '\&', '\?' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*
```

In the beginning, there could be anything.

Then comes one of these things:

```
youtu.be/    (that's the intention, but actually the dot can be any char)
v/
u/some letter/
embed/
watch?v=
&v=
```

The thing that comes above becomes match[1].

Then comes zero or more characters that are not #& or ?
Those characters become match[2].

In the end comes anything.

Answer (score 0):

`/^.*` begining with any character

```
(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)
```

match any of these:

- youtu*be/  <-- probably should be youtu.be
- v/
- u/w/
- watch?v=
- &v=

  ([^#\&\?]*)

followed by anythin but # & and ? symbol

```
.*/
```

any character till the end